# Read from a file and store it in 2d array

Tags: c

I am working on a function that reads from a file (fp) and stores in the words array. I declared MAX_WORD_SIZE as 128, but when I input any file into this function and check with valgrind, it tells me I have an uninitialized value in the line "while(getline(&line,&count,fp)!=-1)" I really don't get it: what is the uninitialised value? My fp file is valid and the word array is also declared well. Thank you in advance.

```
#include "functions.h"
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_file(FILE *fp, char words[][MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1], int size) {
  int i=0;int j=0;
  size_t count=MAX_WORD_SIZE;
  char* line=malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE);
  
  while(getline(&line,&count,fp)!=-1){
    for(;count>0;count--,j++){
      sscanf(line,"%c",&words[i][j]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  int totalNums = i;
  int totalNum = j;
  if (i<size){
    return 1;
  }
  
  
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the function that I called this read_file function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "functions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 const char* fileName = argv[1];
  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Invalid input file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  int size = 0;
  int validity = fscanf(fp, "%d", &size);
  int returnValue = 0;
  char words[size][MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1];
  if(validity != 1 || size <= 0) {
    printf("The first line is not a valid number\n");
    return 1;
  }
  returnValue = read_file(fp, words, size);
  if (returnValue == 1) {
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also post the code which defined/initializes/allocates the parameters that are passed to your function

Comment: In the main function you check the validity of the input for `size` *after* you use `size`. What do you think would happen if the input is not valid?

Comment: You also have a memory leak in the `read_file` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am sorry, I should have mentioned that the number that is first read (or size) is valid. I will try to fix the memory leak and see if it properly runs. Thank you,

Comment: Oh, and remember that [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) can *reallocate* the buffer, which means it might become bigger than `MAX_WORD_SIZE`.